# How do I obtain a shorter output (ciphertext) result from RSA 1024-bit encryption?

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, rsa

I understand that the output of RSA encryption will be equal to the length of the key's modulus (128 bytes in this case). The code for my RSA encryption is:

```
public byte [] RSAEncrypter () throws Exception {
  byte[] inBytes = textfield1.getString().getBytes(); 
  if (newRSApubKey == null){
    throw new Exception("Generate RSA keys first!");
  }
  AsymmetricBlockCipher eng = new RSAEngine();
  eng = new PKCS1Encoding(eng);
  eng.init(true, newRSApubKey);
  return eng.processBlock(inBytes, 0, inBytes.length);
}
```

I processed the resulting output using hex encoding to obtain 256 characters as follows;

```
textfield2.setString(new String(hex.encode(eng.processBlock(inBytes, 0, 
inBytes.length))));
```

I processed the same output using base64 encoding to obtain 172 characters as follows;

```
textfield3.setString(new String(Base64.encode(eng.processBlock(inBytes, 0,
inBytes.length))));
```

However, I saw a PDF available [here](http://www.cscjournals.org/csc/manuscript/Journals/IJCSS/volume3/Issue6/IJCSS-169.pdf) in which the authors were able to obtain 128 characters; even though they did not mention how this is arrived at. Please, I think it’s as a result of the encoding (right?) used. What encoding alternative do I have? Or what do I do to this line of code to achieve an output of of at least 128 characters?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get 128 characters is to treat each byte as if it were a character. In that case you must allow characters that are outside of the printable range, so you must allow everything below `0x20` and `7F`. You could get this by using a C / C++ array of characters (`char*` or `char[]`) and storing the length, as C does not separate between characters and bytes. So in that sense it may just be a linguistic confusion.